# exclude specific url from https using .htacces

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have setup of http to https redirection for whole domain in my .htacces file. All is working fine, but I need exclude one specific subpage from https.

I used code below, but it works only in case when I try access to this sub-page directly in browser, but when I am going through link from my another sub-page (which have to be on https) there is no change and still is on https.
Simply I need all sites which contains detail2.php on HTTP.

Example of my link:
https://www.exampledomain.com/detail2.php?master_id=123

My .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/detail2
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/detail2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The variable %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}  I have to use due to server settings which uses it instead of %{HTTPS}
I have tried a lot of guides here,but nothing work for me.

For whole site redirection also works for me this version:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https

RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA,NE]
```

Thanx a lot for any help.

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Comment: Hi, I tried but nothing changed...tested on chrome/firefox/edge...do you think that code in my htaccess is ok? thanx.